# Automation testing Selenium with c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am able to go till Parent folder and after on Click Childs will display.

how to write method to get dispalyed child (ON CLICK).

I tried this,

```
public void TAB1SELECT() { 
   Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
   action.MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='dijit__TreeNode_14']/div[1]/span[3]/span[1] "))).Build().Perform(); 
   var element = (new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("dijit__TreeNode_36_label"))); 
   element[-1].Click(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: elaborate your question with some more data like  what you have tried, your elements xpaths etc

Comment: I tried with  public void TAB1SELECT()
        { 
                Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
                action.MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dijit__TreeNode_14']/div[1]/span[3]/span[1] "))).Build().Perform();
             var element = (new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("dijit__TreeNode_36_label")));
               element[-1].Click();

        }
        }

Comment: Getting failed at place element[-1].Click();}}

Comment: is it possible to share the app url?

Comment: inorder to veiw application, pulse we need to connect and it is secured, others cannot access

Comment: gotcha give me some time

Comment: Can i share image here  to show u??

Comment: ya that would be great

Comment: GE REPORTS - // This is the Parent and After Clicking on parent Arrow Childs will displays in below format.
   
I am able to reach till GE reports with below code
public IWebElement RP1
        {
            get
            {

                return (new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("dijit__TreeNode_14_label")));

            }
        }
Issue: unable to click on Parent Arrow And open Childs.
How to write method for this?????

Comment: i am unable to attach here

Answer (score 0):

As you intend to click so instead of `PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` you need to use [`VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy.htm). Additionally, instead of using index as `-1` you need to use the index **`0`** for the first element and so on. So your effective code block will be:

```
public void TAB1SELECT() { 
   new Actions(_driver).MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='dijit__TreeNode_14']/div[1]/span[3]/span[1] "))).Build().Perform(); 
   var element = (new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("dijit__TreeNode_36_label"))); 
   element[0].Click(); 
  } 
}
```